# Javascript: Timed href change

Tags: javascript, jquery

Having a slight Javascript issue at the moment, I am hoping to have the below image have a variable HREF which is triggered by a time change.

At the moment it is triggering to some extent but then getting stuck on one of the URLs. It is also affecting an image which is overlaid on top of this one. Which isn't the aim at all!

Any help would be great. Thanks.

```
<div style="position: absolute; left: 0; top: 0; z-index: 100"><a href="[VARIABLE     URL]"><img src="[BACKGROUNDIMAGE]" style="position: absolute top: 0; left: 0;"/></a></div>

<script type="text/JavaScript">

setTimeout(hyperlink1,3000);
setTimeout(hyperlink2,3000); 
setTimeout(hyperlink3,3000);

function hyperlink1 () {
$("a").attr("href", "[URL1]")
}

function hyperlink2 () {
$("a").attr("href", "[URL2]")
}

function hyperlink3 () {
$("a").attr("href", "[URL3]")
}

</script>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your selector, `"a"`, will match all `a` elements on the page. That means all three of your functions, all of which are fired after roughly three seconds, will change all of the links to the same URL.

You need to have each selector be specific to the link it's going to change. You can do that with `id`s on the links, or by their (original) `href`, or using a `class`, etc.

Also note that all three of your functions are being fired at almost exactly the same time. If that's your goal, just use a single function to do all the updates. If your goal is to have one fire, then the next, then the next, either chain them:

```
setTimeout(hyperlink1,3000);

function hyperlink1 () {
    $("a").attr("href", "[URL1]")
    setTimeout(hyperlink2,3000); 
}

function hyperlink2 () {
    $("a").attr("href", "[URL2]")
    setTimeout(hyperlink3,3000);
}

function hyperlink3 () {
    $("a").attr("href", "[URL3]")
}
```

...or use a single function which walks through an array. It depends on how complex the real functions will be and whether you're trying to repeatedly update just one link, or update a series of links one at a time.

If you have just the one link, and you're just trying to update it repeatedly, you might just walk an array like this:

```
function update() {
    var index = 0,
        urls = [
          "/path/to/first",
          "/path/to/second",
          "/path/to/third"
        ];
     setTimeout(tick, 3000);

     function tick() {
         var href = urls[index++];
         if (href) {
             $("a").attr("href", href);
             if (index < urls.length) {
                 setTimeout(tick, 3000);
             }
         }
     }
}
update();
```

...but if it's really just the three you've listed, well, the three functions chained via `setTimeout` is concise and clear. Concise and clear are Good Things<sup>(tm)</sup>.

Comment: The HTML for the page is right there in the question - there's only one `<a>` element, so the selector is fine. How this got one upvote - let alone four (at the time I'm writing this comment - is beyond me.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist: There is not a page of HTML in the question. There is an *excerpt*.

Comment: Concise and clear are good things, and as I'm a complete noob very helpful. It worked perfectly, I would absolutely mark up your response but I cannot!!! Thanks TJ!

Comment: @DaffyKyle: Good deal, glad that helped! :-)

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to change the from one URL to other after 3 secs. Try below,

```
var timer = setInterval(hyperlink,3000);
var ptr = 0;
var urls = ['URL1', 'URL2', 'URL3'];

function hyperlink () {
   if (ptr == url.length) {
      clearInterval(timer);
      ptr = 0;
      return;
   }
   $("a").attr("href", urls[ptr++])
}
```

Answer (score 0):

All your timeouts fire after the same time (about three seconds). That make one of your three URLs functions "win" as it will be called as the last one of three within the very short timespan of  processing the timeout and running your functions.
Most likely the last function will be the one whose URL will be set.
If you want the changes to be cyclic you should do something like this:

```
<script type="text/JavaScript">
hyperlink(0);
function hyperlink(urlCounter) {
    if (urlCounter > 3) {
        urlCounter = 0;
    }
    var url = "";
    switch (urlCounter) {
       case 0:
           url = "[URL 1]";
       break;
       case 1:
           url = "[URL 2]";
       break;
       case 2:
           url = "[URL 3]";
       break;
    }
    setTimeout(function() {
        $("a").attr("href", url)
        urlCounter++;
        hyperlink(urlCounter);
    }, 3000);
}
</script>
```